# File format not supported but when decoding it with base64 it works fine

Tags: javascript, node.js, base64, image-file, backblaze

Hello i'm having issue with uploading image to the cloud ([Backblaze B2](https://www.backblaze.com/b2/cloud-storage.html)).

The problem is, when I use the example Thunder client to upload the file everything works fine and file is shown.

Now my problem is that when I upload with JS I don't know why it is corrupted or bugged.
Like when I upload an image and download it, Windows File Manager says : `file format not supported.`

I decoded the file with base64 img decoder and it works fine and image is shown.

```
const submitForm = () => {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            // binary data
            let imagedata = reader.result.slice(reader.result.indexOf(',') + 1)

            console.log(imagedata);

            console.log(sha1(imagedata));
            const proxyurl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";

            let datadf = fetch(proxyurl + 'url', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        "Accept": "*/*",
                        "User-Agent": "Thunder Client (https://www.thunderclient.io)",
                        "X-Bz-File-Name": file.name,
                        "X-Bz-Content-Sha1": "do_not_verify",
                        "Authorization": "auth",
                        "Content-Type": "b2/x-auto",

                    },
                    body: imagedata,
                })
                .then((response) => {

                    return response.json();
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    return {
                        status: 'fail',
                        message: 'API CALL ERROR',
                        error: err.message
                    };
                });
            datadf.then(res => console.log(res))
        };
        reader.onerror = function(e) {
            // error occurred
            console.log('Error : ' + e.type);
        };
```

Comment: So don't encode it

Comment: @Justinas what u mean by it? BackBlaze require base64 data i'm just sending that data like thunder client , i'm making the same request as thunder client and mine somehow not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[.readAsDataURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL) converts the file it reads into Base64, so it can be represented as a URL you can put into a browser. A very long URL, but still a URL.

If you store a Base 64 representation of an image into a file on your machine, then try to read it with an image-display program, the operation will fail: "This doesn't look like a .jpg, .png, or .gif" so I don't know what to do with it." That's what your Windows file manager error message means.

If you want the file's contents raw rather than Base64 encoded, you'll need to use [.readAsArrayBuffer()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsArrayBuffer).

Comment: Wow this is interesting. This is working. i was looking to thunder clinet request and it sends base64 data... as you can see here : https://i.imgur.com/0C2cU6y.png  i don't know why their base64 data works fine...